# Quartz Job listeners thread safety

Tags: listener, quartz-scheduler

I have one `Listener` for all jobs, and in this listener I have a `List` (for adding and removing data).

Are `jobToBeExecuted`,`jobToBeExecuted` methods thread safe?

Should I use `Collections.synchronizedList`?

Answer (score 0):

No - you must worry about thread safety yourself.

I get the answer from QuartzScheduller's blog.

Answered by James House.